# Executing a PostgreSQL query with an EXCEPTION results in two different ERROR messages

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an PostgreSQL query that includes a transaction and an exception if a column is duplicated:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE "public"."cars" 
  ADD COLUMN "top_speed" text;
EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_column THEN NOTHING;
ROLLBACK;
```

In this query I am trying to add a column that already exists (playing a little bit with exceptions) and if it does then the query shall just ignore it. At the moment I am not really sure if the exception-code I am using is the right (couldn't find a site where they are described; only found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/errcodes-appendix.html))

My Problem is if I execute this query I get the error-message:

> ERROR:  column "top_speed" of relation "cars" already exists

And if I execute it a second time the error-message changes to:

> ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block

Comment: You are mixing up SQL and PL/pgSQL. You can use a `DO` statement, but then you cannot have a semicolon after `BEGIN` (it starts a block, not a transaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html). As Laurenz mentioned, you were mixing PL/pgSQL and SQL commands.

Sample table

```
CREATE TABLE t (f1 TEXT);
```

Anonymous code block

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT count(column_name) FROM information_schema.columns 
      WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND
            table_name = 't' AND
            column_name = 'f2') = 0 THEN 
      ALTER TABLE public.t ADD COLUMN "f2" text;    
  END IF;
END$$;
```

After execution you have your new column. If the column already exists, it will do nothing.

```
SELECT * FROM t;
 f1 | f2 
----+----
0 Zeilen
```

In PostgreSQL 9.6+ you can use `IF NOT EXISTS` to check if a given column already exists in the table before creating it:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS f2 TEXT;
```

Code at [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=0cc08652e76fc8b588c5a35c014082dc)