# manage reference table with foreign keys on new incoming data in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a reference table (in Postgres) and multiple other tables which can reference data in/from this table. It would make sense to use foreign keys to manage this, but I was wondering how one could manage updating the entries in the reference table in the best way when new values come in.
I guess it could be done through the coding that handles the data ingestion and check and insert new values in the reference and after that add the data to the other table. This doesn't seem ideal somehow to me, so I wondered what the best practice is in handling this situation. As there is management of deletion present in SQL I wondered if the opposite might also be available for instance? (not to prevent insertion, but sort of cascading of the values?)

Example reference table;

```
company_id - company_name
1 - test1
2 - test2
3 - test3
```

table with sales to companies:

```
company_id - month - year - sales
1 - January - 2020 - 10000
2 - January - 2020 - 8000
1 - December - 2019 - 9000
3 - November - 2019 - 7000
```

Now data can come in including rows like;

```
company_name - month - year - sales
test4 - January - 2020 - 10000
test5 - January - 2020 - 1000
```

Ideally I could insert this with one query and update the reference table with the new company name so that it gets an id that will be used in the sales table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if the record in the reference table [`exists`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-subquery.html) ..

```
SELECT 
  EXISTS(
    SELECT TRUE FROM company
    WHERE name = 'test2');
```

And in case it does you can insert the sales normally making reference to the company table. If it does not, you can use a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) to insert the new company and get its id, so that you can outside the `CTE` insert the new sales record ..

```
WITH j AS (
  INSERT INTO company (name) 
  VALUES ('test2')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO sales (company_id, sales)
SELECT j.id, 42000 FROM j;
```

Testing script to add a new company

```
CREATE TABLE company (
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT);
INSERT INTO company (name) VALUES ('test1');

CREATE TABLE sales (
company_id INTEGER REFERENCES company(id),
sales NUMERIC);


WITH j AS (
  INSERT INTO company (name) 
  VALUES ('test2')
  RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO sales (company_id, sales)
SELECT j.id, 42000 FROM j;


SELECT * FROM sales
JOIN company ON company.id = sales.company_id;

 company_id | sales | id | name  
------------+-------+----+-------
          2 | 42000 |  2 | test2
(1 Zeile)
```

If you want to ignore records that violate the foreign key constraint, check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224509/2275388) by @a_horse_with_no_name.

**Edit**: Using [`anonymous code blocks`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-do.html) including checks and inserts

```
DO $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS(SELECT TRUE FROM company WHERE name = 'test1') THEN 
      INSERT INTO sales (company_id, sales)
      VALUES ((SELECT id FROM company WHERE name = 'test1'),42000);
  ELSE
    WITH j AS (
      INSERT INTO company (name) 
      VALUES ('test1')
      RETURNING id
    )
    INSERT INTO sales (company_id, sales)
    SELECT j.id, 42000 FROM j;
  END IF;
END$$;
```

Comment: thanks! I guess it should be possible to combine the check and the insert using CASE? (want to see if I can get down to 1 query)

Comment: @Chrisvdberge I'm afraid it is not possible to combine queries like this in pure SQL. Would it be an option to use `plpgsql`? Using an anonymous code block it would be much easier do do what you want

Comment: @Chrisvdberge maybe this answer will give you an idea of what I am talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59712952/2275388

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction ;) I'm using python and sqlalchemy for this and it seems it allows me to use plpgsql and anonymous code block